# Count the number of rows matching a couple of pattern (AND operators) from a vector

Tags: r

I have dataset :

```
dataset <- c("male Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet female consectetur, adipisci velit young",
   "est qui dolorem tall dolorem ipsum  female Neque young",
   "male, female porro old")

dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)
```

I have a keywords list :

```
 keywords <- c("male", "female", "young")
```

I can count the number of rows containing "words":

```
sapply(keywords, function(x) length(grep(x, dataset$dataset, ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

My result :

```
 male female  young 
   3      3      2
```

What I want : count the number of rows that match the combinaison of keywords (AND operator).

- number of rows with male AND female : 2
- number of rows with male AND young : 1
- number of rows female AND young : 2
- number of rows male AND young : 1

Comment: @Limey  it's what I did.

Comment: I saw it before you added the code.  Thank you.

Comment: Why is female & young count 1? Doesn't it exist in rows 1 and 2?

Comment: @Sotos it's an error in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `stri_extract_all_regex` to get all `keywords`. Then loop over that list combine to get pairs, `unlist` and use `table` to count, i.e.

```
library(stringi)

table(unlist(sapply(stri_extract_all_regex(dataset$dataset, paste(keywords, collapse = '|')),
                                                          function(i)combn(i, 2, toString))))

#female, young  male, female   male, young 
#            2             2             1
```

Comment: Why collapse | and not & ?

Comment: We don't care about getting the pairs yet. We first need to extract words that match either 'this' or 'that'. The `AND` part comes when we take the pairs (i.e. the `combn()` part)

Comment: ok. With my real data `combn` returns me  `Error in combn(i, 2, toString) : n < m` because in some text I have only female or Male, no combinaisons or no keywords.. I don't find NA omit option

Comment: Ok I am going **first** to filter with keywords.

Answer (score 0):

From the online doc: "`grepl` returns a logical vector (match or not for each element of x)"

So

```
flags <- sapply(keyword, function(x) length(grepl(x, dataset$dataset, ignore.case = TRUE)))
```

will give you vectors of indicator variables showing which elements of `dataset` contain each keyword.  Then you should be able to just `&` them together.

```
sum(flags$male & flags&female)
```

[Untested code]

To generate all combinations of two or more keywordfs, the `combinations` function from the `arrangements` package is useful.

```
library(arrangements)

keywords <- c("male", "female", "young", "old")
combos <- lapply(2:length(keywords), function(k) combinations(keywords, k))
```

Then you can just iterate through `combos` to get totals you want.

Comment: I want to have all the combinaisons. I the real data I have dozens of keywords.