# Count the number of rows matching a couple of pattern from a vector (version 2: avoid duplicate count, deal with strings without patterns)

Tags: r

I have a dataset (new version from my first post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304073/count-the-number-of-rows-matching-a-couple-of-pattern-and-operators-from-a-vec):

```
 dataset <- c("male Neque  female consectetur  young, young",
         "est  female Neque young",
         "male, female porro old")

dataset <- as.data.frame(dataset)



keywords <- c("male", "female", "young")
```

Based on @sotos answer from my first reprex [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62304073/count-the-number-of-rows-matching-a-couple-of-pattern-and-operators-from-a-vec):

```
library(stringi)

table(unlist(sapply(stri_extract_all_regex(dataset$dataset, paste(keywords, collapse = '|')),
                  function(i)combn(i, 2, toString))))
```

I found :

```
female, young  male, female   male, young  young, young 
           3             2             2             1
```

- First question : How to avoid duplicates on count : the pair of female and young are count 2 times in the first string.
- How to avoid error `Error in combn(i, 2, toString) : n < m` when I introduce strings that not contains keywords like in this dataset2 :

  ```
  dataset2 <- c("male Neque  female consectetur  young, young",
       "est  female Neque young",
       "male, female porro old",
       "lrem ipsum")

   dataset2 <- as.data.frame(dataset2)
  ```

Real dataset and words [here](https://github.com/wilcar/sgf/tree/master)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done only with `combn` :

```
values <- combn(keywords, 2, function(x) 
     sum(grepl(paste0('\\b', x[1],'\\b'), dataset$dataset, ignore.case = TRUE) & 
         grepl(paste0('\\b', x[2],'\\b'), dataset$dataset,  ignore.case = TRUE)))
values
#[1] 2 1 2
```

To understand which numbers represent what you can do

```
data.frame(key = combn(keywords, 2, toString), values)

#            key values
#1  male, female      2
#2   male, young      1
#3 female, young      2
```

Comment: working but with real data strange results ..You will find my real df and keywords in my update post

Comment: @Wilcar It returns me an error `Error in nchar(x) : invalid multibyte string, element 2`

Comment: The xls file is valid for me I can download it.

Comment: @Wilcar I can download it to, I cannot open it. It gives me that error message in R.

Comment: you ll find the RDS version a the file too

Comment: did you tried `library(readxl)` / `labels_rec <- read_excel("labels_rec.xls")` it works for me

Comment: @Wilcar I turned the file to csv and was able to read it. you have different cases in `words` and columns. Add `ignore.case = TRUE` in `grepl` and it should work. This worked for me `values <- combn(words, 2, function(x) sum(grepl(paste0('\\b', x[1],'\\b'), labels_rec$LIBELLE, ignore.case = TRUE) & grepl(paste0('\\b', x[2],'\\b'), labels_rec$LIBELLE, ignore.case = TRUE)))` I have also updated the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215791/discussion-between-wilcar-and-ronak-shah).

Answer (score 2):

For your first case you can just add `unique()` insisde of `combn()` to avoid the duplicated words. i.e.

```
table(unlist(sapply(stri_extract_all_regex(dataset$dataset, paste(keywords, collapse = '|')),
                   function(i) combn(unique(i), 2, toString))))

#female, young  male, female   male, young 
#            2             2             1
```

As for your second case you can use `Filter` to remove entries with only 1 element, i.e.

```
table(unlist(sapply(Filter(function(x) length(x) > 1, stri_extract_all_regex(dataset2$dataset2, paste(keywords, collapse = '|'))),
                   function(i) combn(unique(i), 2, toString))))

#female, young  male, female   male, young 
#            2             2             1
```

Comment: not working with my real data. You  will find my real df and keywords in my update post